# Stella SDK convert to android

Tags: android, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to use the stella SDK to convert my iOS app made in cocos2d 1.1 rc0 to an android project. When I use the method on here: http://www.yeecco.com/support/docs/getting_started#portingiosprojectswithstellasdk

I get the error: `Lexical or pre-processor Issue: 'GL/gl.h' file not found`

This occurs even when I follow part one of the tutorial in which you convert the GLSprite test project to an android project. I have no idea how to solve this issue, especially as the issue is occurring in the same file that it says isn't included!...

Here's a screenshot [image]

Comment: I'm experiencing exactly the same problem. I use android NDK r8c, whereas the document uses r7b. @simonthumber: Which one do you use?

Comment: r7b I believe... I'll check for you when I'm next at my laptop.

Comment: @simonthumber: Did you check this?

Comment: Ooooooop my bad, completely forgot! Just checked and I'm using the r7b NDK...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has been tearing me. And I finally found the SDKROOT should be OS X 10.7 .

1. Set **TARGETS-> Build-> Settings-> SDKROOT-> OS X 10.7**.
2. And then install **X11** http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/
3. after installing, you log out of account from mac, log in again and run this project.

That's all!

Comment: By the way, how do you know the Stella SDK?

Answer (score 2):

I found a fix.

On the Xcode project generated by StellaSDK, set the Base SDK for the target to OS X 10.7. Then add this to the “Header Search Paths” field in your target's build settings:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/X11/include
```

You will also need to install XQuartz following [Apple instructions](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5293) for it to work.

Cheers!

Comment: I'll give this a try as soon as I get a chance and let you know how it goes :D

Comment: apologies been busy with Christmas and revising for January uni exams... I'll give it a try when the exams are over next week!

Comment: Did that and it got rid of some errors but it's still throwing up a load... Couldn't find "cocos2d.h", couldn't find "CCLayer.h" e.t.c :/

Comment: Tried it on another project which also got rid of the Gl.h error but now get `'kazmath/neon_matrix_impl.h' file not found`